# GIS and natural disasters - examples of geo-visualizations and geospatial analysis

Tags: web-mapping, visualisation, natural-disaster

I stumbled upon NY Times' [web map](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2011/04/28/us/tornado-deaths.html) of deaths from tornadoes in US.

[image]

Can you point me to some more interesting examples of geo-visualization and/or geospatial analysis of natural disasters and their consequences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Nature (Geological) and Man-made structures are areas of concern...

[image: Earthquake Activity Map with Nuclear Power Stations]

[source](http://mapperz.blogspot.com/2011/03/earthquake-activity-nuclear-power.html)

Answer (score 5):

In [the French geoportal](http://www.geoportail.fr/), there is [a data layer showing the consequences of the storm Klaus](http://www.geoportail.fr/visu2D.do?cg=djoxLjEqYzptZXRyb3BvbGUqY3Y6MS4wKnZ2OjEuMSp4eTotMC45NzEzNTEwMjY3MDY4NDI2fDQ0LjE0MzU5OTU2MTI2MjAxKnM6MTEqcHY6MS4wKnA6ZGVjb3V2ZXJ0ZSpsOlBob3RvfDF8MTAwfDAsa2xhdXN8MXwxMDB8NDE=) (january 2009) on the forested areas at the parcel level.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Tilemill has a few good examples with earthquakes, such as [this one from Japan](http://www.flickr.com/photos/developmentseed/5572642766/), and [this interactive map application](http://www.flickr.com/photos/developmentseed/5520015185/in/photostream/).

Answer (score 4):

Esri's [disaster response site](http://www.esri.com/services/disaster-response/) has several such examples:
[image: Esri Disaster Response]

[Google Crisis Response](http://www.google.com/crisisresponse/response.html) is another such resource:

[image: Google]

Comment: There is also one for wildfires in US now: http://www.esri.com/services/disaster-response/wildlandfire/latest-news-map.html

Answer (score 3):

In response to the Tohoku Earthquake and Tsunami Mar 11th 2011, the Harvard Center for Geographic Analysis has launched [this web portal](http://cegrp.cga.harvard.edu/japan/).

Answer (score 3):

[Japan Quake Map](http://www.japanquakemap.com/)

Quote from their About page: "The Japan Quake Map on this website presents a time-lapse visualisation of the Sendai earthquake and its aftershocks, primarily to help those outside the affected area understand what the people of Japan are experiencing. It plots earthquake data from USGS on a map using the Google Maps API, with the size of the circle denoting the magnitude (the higher the magnitude, the larger the circle) and the colour showing the focal depth (see the legend below the map)."

Answer (score 3):

[GIS Use in Public Health and Health Care blog](https://healthmap.wordpress.com/) has a list of US tornado related visualizations, among them this [NY Times one](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2011/04/28/us/map-of-the-tornadoes-across-the-south.html):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Apparently in US tornadoes frequency doesn't correlate with amount of deaths@

[image]

Via [highlyallochthonous](http://all-geo.org/highlyallochthonous/2011/05/natural-disasters-may-not-always-hit-hardest-where-youd-expect/)

Answer (score 3):

The drought in a part of Africa this year caused the biggest in 60 years famine in this particular region. The range of this phenomenon is precisely and constantly documented by the European SMOS satellite ([Soil Moisture and Ocean Salinity Satellite](http://download.esa.int/multimedia/earthobservation/smos_somalia_anv2.gif))

[image]

UPDATE: [Drying of soils in Central and Eastern Europe](http://download.esa.int/multimedia/20102011Nov_H.gif)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Colombian mission of the [United Nations Office for the Coordination of Human Affairs](http://www.unocha.org/) (UN OCHA) produced a map collection for the [2008](http://www.colombiassh.org/site/spip.php?article365) and [2010 floods in Colombia](http://www.colombiassh.org/site/spip.php?article643) as well as other [natural disasters](http://www.colombiassh.org/site/spip.php?id_mot=41&id_rubrique=22&page=buscamapas1).

[image: Floods in Colombia - Magdalena, Atlantico, and Bolivar]